# sql developer export is adding additional double quote

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table in oracle with entries like this:

Table t1:

| attribute1 | attribute2 |
| --- | --- |
| abc | def"ghi |

I am trying to run following sql:

```
select attribute1||'|'||attribute2 t1;
```

I am exporting the results from sql developer as text file and I am seeing following in the text file:

```
ATTRIBUTE1||'|'||ATTRIBUTE2

abc|def""ijk
```

How can I remove the additional double quote during export by sql developer?

As of now, I am only removing it from text file using find and replace which is not ideal.

Comment: As a workaround you may specity `delimited` as export format (and set pipe as delimiter instead of concatenation) or `csv`. It doesn't add another quote if you set both enclosures to `none`

Comment: Thanks a lot @astentx. It worked for me.